# Convert.ToSingle() for float data Type

Tags: c#

I have used many of the Convert.To..... functions for conversion , but I didn't understand one thing that for every datatype they have provide a Convert.To function but not for float datatype, in order to convert to float you need to use Convert.ToSingle() , why is this so ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Single is the CTS (Common Type System for .NET) type, float is the C# shorthand for it.

```
Int32 CTS -> int C#
String CTS -> string C#
Double CTS -> double C#
Single CTS -> float C#
Int16 CTS -> short C#
Int64 CTS -> long C#
```

etc.

The Convert methods are .NET methods and therefore use the CTS names and not the C# shorthands.